# Should I derive custom exceptions from Exception or ApplicationException in .NET?

Tags: .net, exception

What is best practice when creating your exception classes in a .NET solution: To derive from `System.Exception` or from `System.ApplicationException`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to Jeffery Richter in the Framework Design Guidelines book:

> `System.ApplicationException` is a class that should not be part of the .NET framework.

It was intended to have some meaning in that you could potentially catch "all" the application exceptions, but the pattern was not followed and so it has no value.

Comment: Incredible when one considers the Microsoft Press material for the MCTS 70-536 exam clearly says the opposite... gah!

Comment: Never fully trust MS exam books. I've read few of them - always full of errors.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  Are you saying that custom application exceptions should inherit from `Exception`?  If so, could you say so?

Answer (score 33):

You should derive custom exceptions from `System.Exception`.

Even MSDN now says to ignore `ApplicationException`:

> If you are designing an application
>   that needs to create its own
>   exceptions, you are advised to derive
>   custom exceptions from the Exception
>   class. It was originally thought that
>   custom exceptions should derive from
>   the ApplicationException class;
>   however in practice this has not been
>   found to add significant value. For 
>   more information, see [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx

Comment: The quote does say that, but ok, edited to be more explicit.

Answer (score 18):

[`ApplicationException` considered useless](https://web.archive.org/web/20190904221653/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2006/06/23/applicationexception-considered-useless/) is a strong, and critical, argument against `ApplicationException`.

Upshot: don't use it. Derive from `Exception`.

Comment: Yeah, Konrad has it right. On a related note: another thing thought useful (or "best practice") but really isn't is [implementing ICloneable](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

The authors of the framework themselves consider ApplicationException worthless:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190904221653/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2006/06/23/applicationexception-considered-useless/

with a nice follow-up here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190828075736/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2006/07/05/choosing-the-right-type-of-exception-to-throw/

When in doubt, I follow their book Framework Design Guidelines.

[http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development/dp/0321246756](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)

The topic of the blog post is further discussed there.

rp

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to do:

```
private void buttonFoo_Click()
{
    try
    {
       foo();
    } 
    catch(ApplicationException ex)
    {
      Log.UserWarning(ex);
      MessageVox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       Log.CodeError(ex);
       MessageBox.Show("Internal error.");
    }
}
```

It allow to do the difference between:

- C# code system error that I must repairs.
- "Normal" user error that do not need correction from me.

I know it is not recommended to use ApplicationException, but it works great since there is [very few classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx) that do not respect the ApplicationException pattern.

Comment: Very few that you know about. Anyone following the Framework Design Guidelines will not be deriving from ApplicationException. If you want to maintain this pattern, then you need to create your own type like MyApplicationExcptionBase and derive all of your custom exceptions from that. BTW, the Guidelines say to create few derived exception types.

Comment: You right: today, if I had to start from scratch, I will create a "UserError" Exception. Nevertheless, I will not refactor my old code: it is not very critique.