# How to remote exception through .NET Remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-remoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Remoting Exception not handled Client-Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498772/net-remoting-exception-not-handled-client-side)

I have a client-server applicaytion working with .NET Remoting. Server contains a class (RemoteClass) which contains a method throwing exception. But this exception crushes server instead of being handled by client try/catch block. My code looks like:

```
//Common library
public class RemoteClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
  public void SomeMethod ()
  {
   throw new NotSupportedException (); //Standart exception with Serializible attribute
  }
}

//Client-side code
try
{ //remote is instance of remoteobject,the other its methods work fine
  remote.SomeMethod (); 
}
catch(exception e) 
{
 //I want to handle exception here
}
```

But as I mentioned above my server-side is crushed...( Is there a way to do what I want via .NET Remoting?

Comment: Regardless of marking answer as acceptable, there is no real answer on that question too. I have read that topic before to post my one.