# Which class should be used as base class of custom exception in .NET?

Tags: .net, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I derive custom exceptions from Exception or ApplicationException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753/should-i-derive-custom-exceptions-from-exception-or-applicationexception-in-net)

I've found two controversial thoughts in MSDN for this matter.

> If you are designing an application that needs to create its own exceptions, derive from the ApplicationException class.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> For most applications, derive custom exceptions from the Exception  class.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/seyhszts%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Additionally when I took some practice test for 70-536 there was similar question and as right answer was marked ApplicationException.

What is the official guideline?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753/should-i-derive-custom-exceptions-from-exception-or-applicationexception-in-net

Comment: Yeah, I see it already. Can I delete my own question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ApplicationException` was the first recommendation, but after a while MS decided that it just increased the inheritance depth without giving any advantage so they changed the recommendation to just use `Exception`.

You can find some more information (including a quote explaining the rationale) in this blog post: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kcwalina/applicationexception-considered-useless)

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The short answer is that the `ApplicationException` class in unofficially deprecated/obsolete, for a number of reasons. (The main one is perhaps that the exception type should/need not indicate source (that's what the `Source` property is for.)

Originally (.NET 1.x days I believe) it was intended that you would derive all custom exception classes from it to differentiate from BCL exceptions, but this was later (rightly in my view) disregarded. The common/good practice these days is to derive all custom exception classes directly from `Exception` (or other custom classes).

Answer (score 1):

Exception is your best bet, in my opinion.

In my opinion and some others that I have read, ApplicationException was a overengineering at its best.

There are more opinions [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2004/05/10/129134.aspx)