# I'm building an API/Framework in C#, how should I return validation error messages when properties are set to an invalid value?

Tags: c#, frameworks, validation

I'm building an API in C#, how should I return validation error messages when properties are set to invalid values?  Should I throw exceptions or do something else?  What do you recommend?  I could use the AggregateException class from the Task Parallel Library so I can throw more then one at a time.  What are the best practices?

Comment: Are these error messages for API users (programmers) or application users (regular people)?

Comment: That's a good question.  It would be application programmers.

Comment: Here's one issue I have with the exception.  The validation rules are not transparent when you use exceptions.  The programmer has to use trial and error to determine things like valid property length or if the property can be null.  I'd like to be able to push things like validation rules thru the API to whatever program is using the API so the API consumer does not have to duplicate logic from the api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be to throw an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28VS.80%29.aspx) in each property setter when it's set to an invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the property.   Another poster recommended ArgumentException, but I feel that this is more specific to invalid arguments passed to a method.  I would probably create my own Exceptions (inheriting ApplicationExecption) and make them specific to my properties like:

PropertyNumericRangeException ( numeric property with a range 0-100 lets say)

PropertyStringLengthException ( bounding a string length )

I imagine you could extend AggregateException for this purpose as well, but pretty much sky is the limit here...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753/should-i-derive-custom-exceptions-from-exception-or-applicationexception-in-net for best practice on what to derive from.

Comment: If I use this approach as an "enduser" I'd have to check the exception type and if I want to pass along a validation error message to a client then I've got to write a bunch of logic to line up the ui field and the exception message.  What are your recommendations for handling that kind of logic?

Answer (score 0):

Use a validation framework like [Enterprise Library Validation Application Block](http://entlib.codeplex.com/), or you can create your own. Instead of throwing an exception for each validation error report all errors with a single exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the more recent flavours of .NET, and especially if you're going to be working with WPF/Silverlight, then implementing IDataErrorInfo may be a better solution. Karl Shiflett has written [a good article on the pros and cons](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/fort-knox-business-objects-yes-no/) of throwing exceptions in the property setter versus implementing IDataErrorInfo.

> If you have validation rules that are
>   dependent on one or more property
>   values, developers will now have to
>   write code to set property values in a
>   certain order to avoid an exception
>   being thrown.  This is a crazy
>   requirement and is contrary all .NET
>   class design documentation.  Can you
>   imaging having to wrap EVERY piece of
>   code that sets a property with a try
>   catch block.  Again, what about LINQ
>   queries that are tying to populate
>   objects and unnecessary exceptions are
>   being thrown by property setters. 
>   This makes writing maintainable code
>   MUCH harder and with ZERO payback. 
>   When code is changed over time, a
>   field added, we have to factor in
>   usless exception handling and be
>   cognasent of the order in which
>   property setters are called or change.

Comment: I think you are confusing validations with application errors.  The OP is specifically talking about error messages for *programmers*, not users.  Therefore you should *not* catch these exceptions so as to display the message to the end-user in a manner so he can fix his mistake; if you get the exception at all it means you have a **bug**.  So the best thing to do is *not* handle it and let it bubble up and let your global exception handler catch it (if any).