# How do I create a subclass with a constructor that defaults the helplink to google.com?

Tags: c#, exception, class-design, custom-exceptions

I'm trying to write code to create an `EpicFailException` class as a subclass of `ApplicationException`. I have to add a constructor that defaults the `HelpLink` property to [google.com](http://www.google.com). Below is what I have so far. Any suggestions for how to apply the subclass?

```
 public class ApplicationException : Exception
 {
     public ApplicationException(string auxMessage, Exception inner) :
         base()
     {
         this.HelpLink = "http://google.com";
     }
 }
```

Comment: is this a asp.net app or? Do you want to redirect the user to google if this exception happens... and why don't you handle it yourself... what epic exception are you expecting???

Comment: EpicFailException : ApplicationException ?

Comment: I want to redirect the user to google if this exception happens. EpicException is the subclass of ApplicationException.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET class design guidelines have been changed; the [current recommendation is to derive from `Exception` and not from `ApplicationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753/should-i-derive-custom-exceptions-from-exception-or-applicationexception-in-net).

That said, if you have the need to set the `HelpLink` property in a number of derived exceptions, you might want to create a base class which demands the value for the `HelpLink` property as a parameter, and then derive from that:

```
public abstract MyExceptionBase : Exception
{
    protected MyExceptionBase(string message, string helpLink) : 
        base(message)
    {
        HelpLink = helpLink;
    }
}

public MyException : MyExceptionBase
{
    public MyException(string message) : 
        base(message, "http://www.google.com")
    { }
}
```

Note that you should still follow all of the other [guidelines for custom exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx), such as serialization, parameterless constructor, etc.

Comment: I want to write the code to create an EpicFailException class as a subclass of ApplicationException. Then i'm trying to add a constructor that defaults the HelpLink property to "http://google.com".

Comment: @John: The above does what you want, and follows proper .NET design guidelines.  See the links in the answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the question, but you might be looking for

```
base(auxMessage,inner)
```

instead of just

```
base()
```