# Exception Design InvalidParentException and ObjectAlreadyPresentException

Tags: .net

I am designing a Framework library which can be used to store a hierarchically linked set of objects. I need to decide on what exceptions can be thrown by the following methods:

```
class StoreSession {
  StoreLeaf(leaf, parent)
}
```

When users call `StoreLeaf()` passing the params and if the leaf is not hierarchically linked to a parent based on some custom rules that I execute, then I need to throw an exception (something like `InvalidParentException`)

If the object that I am attempting to store already has an entry in the repository, then I also need to throw an exception (something like `ObjectAlreadyPresentException`)

I referred the [FDG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) and also [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/03/27/402801.aspx), there are no instances of any exceptions that describe these 2 scenarios.

Is there any .NET exception that describes these erroneous conditions? Or even If I have to create a new `Exception` type, is there any specific .NET exception that I can derive from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any specific .NET `Exception` that describes these conditions; if there were, they would probably be specific to a data structure that fits your needs and you would be using that instead of writing your own.

That said, when the framework first came out, the initial recommendation was to derive from [`ApplicationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx), however, it was quickly revealed that lead to quite a bit of bloat and was ineffective, so the current practice is to [derive custom exceptions directly from `Exception`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753/should-i-derive-custom-exceptions-from-exception-or-applicationexception-in-net).

However, in your specific case, unless there is an action item you are planning on taking in the face of these exceptions, you should probably just use [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

If you *are* going to perform an action on these exceptions, then you might want to consider whether or not you should use exceptions at all; it's generally bad practice to base business logic off exceptions; you should use return codes/values where possible.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like an exception that should ever be caught.  Since it represents a bug in the client code, a catch handler cannot rewrite code.  As such, there is little point in creating a dedicated exception type for them, something you *have* to do if the exception is intended to be ever caught and handled.

InvalidOperationException with a good exception message is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a guideline for this sort of thing, I tend to try to find an approach for something as similar as possible in the BCL.  For example, IDictionary implementations are [supposed to throw an ArgumentException for a duplicate key passed to the Add(TKey, TValue) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy7xta5e.aspx), which is what Dictionary actually does.  In the absence of any evidence that the BCL authors regret the decision to throw ArgumentException in this case (such as a comment in the annotage FDG), I would tend to re-use their approach for the sake of consistency with existing BCL mechanisms.