# What exception should I throw for an unexpected null value?

Tags: c#, exception

I've been a .NET developer for over a decade so here's a shameful question I've never known the answer to.  I get it--if an argument is null, I can throw an ArgumentNullException.  A NullReferenceException will be thrown if I try to dereference a null value.

But what if I have code like the following:

```
var someVitalObject = someServiceReference.GetVitalObject();

if (someVitalObject == null)
{
  throw new IDontKnowWhatException(); // what exception should I throw here?
}
```

Now, this isn't necessarily a problem with the service for which an exception should have been thrown earlier.

Comment: NullReferenceException?

Comment: Is this being null an error in the execution flow? Will this cause your app to terminate? Perhaps more context will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: So is `GetVitalObject()` breaking its contract, or is it valid for that to return null, but just not in this case?

Comment: Does the API make some guarantee about whether the object can be null or not? If so it might be more of an assertion failure (use Trace.Assert). Otherwise a custom exception like VitalObjectNotFoundException would be appropriate.

Comment: In my case, to make it simpler, pretend that I'm checking the state of a cache to see if it has the "vital object" stored.  It should by then, and if it doesn't then that's a problem.

Answer (score 13):

It's hard to say without seeing more context, but perhaps [`System.InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.invalidoperationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Answer (score 9):

I typically use *ArgumentNullException* for objects passed into a function. Anything else null related I use *InvalidOperationException*. In specialized cases I'll create a custom exception if it makes sense to.

Answer (score 2):

I would only use System.ArgumentNullException when directly checking a method parameter, not when validating the result of some call.

The type of exception I throw depends greatly on the context. But in this case I would probably go for a custom exception like:

```
public class VitalObjectNotAcquiredException : Exception { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to create your own `Exception` class inherited from the `ApplicationException` or from the `Exception`:

```
public sealed class MyException : Exception
{
    ...
}
```

Thus you will be able to control what kind of information to store in it.

Comment: In general inheriting from `ApplicationException` is considered a bad practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753/should-i-derive-custom-exceptions-from-exception-or-applicationexception-in-net

Comment: @juharr Is useless == bad practice? [ApplicationException considered useless](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2006/06/23/644822.aspx): *ApplicationException is not considered harmful, just useless.*

Comment: I guess I was thinking of catching `ApplicationException` as a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I'd choose according to the GetVitalObject method contract. If this method should return a not null object I'd change it so it throws an exception in this case.

If you don't have control over the method or if returning a null value is correct (but not in your context) i'd go with a custom exception as Mark and Dmitry already said.